# converting base64 encoded mail subject to text

Tags: perl, unix, procmail

Set out to write a simple procmail recipie that would forward the mail to me if it found the text "Unprovisioned" in the subject.

```
:0:
* ^Subject:.*Unprovisioned.*
! me@test.com
```

Unfortunately the subject field in the mail message coming from the mail server was in MIME encoded-word syntax.

The form is: **"=?charset?encoding?encoded text?=".**

```
 Subject: =?UTF-8?B?QURWSVNPUlk6IEJNRFMgMTg0NSwgTkVXIFlPUksgLSBVbnByb3Zpc2lvbmVkIENvbm4gQQ==?=
    =?UTF-8?B?bGVydA==?=
```

The above subject is utf-8 charset, base64 encoding with text folded to two lines. So was wondering if there are any mechanisms/scripts/utilities to parse this and convert to string format so that I could apply my procmail filter. Ofcourse I can write a perl script to parse this an perform the required validations, but looking to avoid it if possible.

Comment: If you hit a snag with edge-cases (like wrapped headers, [email and MIME are tricky!](http://www.youtube.com/user/yapcasia#p/u/0/JENdgiAPD6c)), consider switching to [Courriel](http://p3rl.org/Courriel) for parsing the messages.

Comment: Tangentially, the trailing `.*` is redundant.

Answer (score 9):

[Encode::MIME::Header](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode/MIME/Header.html), which ships with Perl, accessed directly through Encode:

```
use Encode qw(encode decode);
my $header_text = decode('MIME-Header', $header);
```